# Адаптация дизайна под разные экраны

Tags: android, android-layout, дизайн, разрешение

Уже задавал подобный вопрос, думал проблема решена, но нет. Вопрос связан с адаптацией дизайна под разные экраны. Я до этого использовал самостоятельно стандартный layout, layout-large и layout-xlarge. После обращения за помощью, мне подсказали использовать layout-sw600dp и layut-sw820dp. Подумал что они мне подходят, но после перехода на них, оказалось, что мне не подходят и они. А не подходят такие разметки потому что layout-large занимает 2 телефонных макета, и это уже смотрится некорректно. А layout-sw600dp занимает не все планшетные разметки, 2 оставляя под телефонные, что опять же смотрится некорректно.
Так вот теперь вопрос, может есть какая то разметка между large и sw600dp, или может есть способ избежать эти разметки и заменить их более адаптивными?

Все судил по своей неопытности в их использовании и по макетам экранов, существующих в Android Studio.

Upd: Да, вы правы, разделяют разметки на телефонные и планшетные они правильно, это я подумал что красные(на скрине) разметки планшетные, так как на них смотрится все, мягко говоря, не очень в отличии от других(синих). С ними то у меня и возникает проблема и вопрос: Как настроить layout отдельно под них?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же 2 чуть менее важных вопроса. Какая версия Android используется в разметках "New Device.." (над красными)? И могу ли я отказаться от использования sw820dp, если считают, что мне хватит и разметки sw600dp, или их лучше использовать вместе?

Comment: вам нужно разделить разметки на телефонные и планшетные?  как правило layout-sw600dp и layut-sw820dp **вместе** довольно корректно делают это. Если это не так, добавьте в вопрос примеры параметров экрана (разрешение, диагональ, плотность) с которыми появляются проблемы

Comment: @pavloff Я обновил вопрос

Comment: для того, что в красном, разметку нужно поместить в папку */layout-large-mdpi* хотя реальных устройств с таким экраном мне вспомнить не удалось. Если вы считаете, что разметка из папки sw600dp полностью подходит для всех типов планшетов, то использовать папку sw820dp (это, как правило, планшеты 10" и более) конечно нет никакой надобности.

Comment: Пункты меню на ваших скриншотах - это физические параметры экранов разных устройств (диагональ и разрешение в пикселях) и никакого отношения к версии Android они не имеют. Любой экран из списка может быть на устройстве и с версией Andoid 2.3  и с  Android 8. Вообще, в разделе *General phones and tablets* собраны типовые размеры экранов многих устройств (что понятно и из названия зраздела), поэтому они не имеют персонального имени устройства. Название *New Device* - просто имя, с таким же успехом оно могло бы быть и, например, Device1 // к версиям Androd это никак не относится.